# Where is the storage location tags in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, tags

WordPress tags are stored where?

There are no tags in the database table.

[image]

tanks!

Answer (score 3):

The tags for posts are stored within the **wp_terms** table.

[Check the refference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_terms)

Also good to know.

**wp_term_relationships** - Posts are associated with categories and tags from the **wp_terms** table and this association is maintained in the **wp_term_relationships** table. The association of links to their respective categories are also kept in this table.
[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_term_relationships)